# Calculating angles between surfaces

Tags: calculus, surfaces

I am given the equations for two surfaces, and I must find the angle between the surface. Would it be correct to find the gradient of the surfaces, and find the angle by taking the dot product of the gradients and taking the cos inverses of the gradients' magnitudes?

Comment: It's the good way...

Comment: So that's a yes?

Comment: **Yes**, it's the good way.

Comment: Thank you so much.